# How to read the change in URL and take some action with WebKit and SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, webkit

I am trying to show a sign in page in app with SwiftUI that will redirect to my other app views, once the sign up is complete, I want o do that by observing the change in URL with SwiftUI and WebKit. Please help? Thank You.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'd suggest using `ASWebAuthenticationSession` for this task instead. I switched because I have more control over than a `UIViewRepresentable`'s with a `WKWebView`. And I can put it in an `ObservableObject` class.